# Splitting behavior of prime pairs in number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

What is the splitting behavior of twin primes in number fields?

For example, given a twin prime pair what can we say about the number fields in which both of them split completely, or remain inert together? Are there number fields in which all twin primes split completely (and only those!)? Given a random number field how often would twin primes show the same ramification behavior?

Or, the other way round, in a given number field which twin primes would simultaneously split completely, or simultaneously remain inert? Or just which proportion of them?

Same can be asked of prime pairs with any given separation.

A variation of the question that also seems interesting is: what is the splitting behavior of consecutive primes in number fields?

Pointers to research along these lines - where additive and algebraic number theories meet -  would be appreciated.

Comment: There's a very simple answer in the case of ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-1})$; out of every twin pair, one splits completely and one's inert.

Comment: "Are there number fields in which all twin primes split completely (and only those!)?" For "and only those", the answer is certainly negative, since primes which split completely always have positive density. For an extension in which all twin primes split, I would conjecture the answer is still no, but we won't prove that without proving the twin prime conjecture.